# Global device variables in CUDA: bad practice?

Tags: cuda

I am designing a library that has a large contingent of CUDA kernels to perform parallel computations.  All the kernels will be acting on a common object, say a computational grid, which is defined using C++ style objects.  The computational domain doesn't necessarily need to be accessed from the host side, so creating it on the device side and keeping it there makes sense for now.  I'm wondering if the following is considered "good practice":

- Suppose my computational grid class is called `Domain`.  First I Define a global device-side variable to store the computational domain:

  ```
  __device__ Domain* D
  ```
- Then I Initialize the computational domain using a CUDA kernel

  ```
  __global__ void initDomain(paramType P){
      D = new Domain(P);
  }
  ```
- Then, I perform computations using this domain with other kernels:

  ```
  __global__ void doComputation(double *x,double *y){
      D->doThing(x,y);
      //...
  }
  ```

If my domain remains fixed (i.e. kernels don't modify the domain once it's created), is this OK?  Is there a better way?  I initially tried creating the `Domain` object on the host side and copying it over to the device, but this turned out to be a hassle because `Domain` is a relatively complex type that makes it a pain to copy over using e.g. `cudaMemCpy` or even `Thrust::device_new` (at least, I couldn't get it to work nicely).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's ok.

Maybe you can improve performance using

```
__constant__
```

using this keyword, your object will be available in all your kernels in a very fast memory.

In order to copy your object, you must use : cudaMemcpyToSymbol, please note there is come restriction : your object will be read-only in your device code, and it **must** don't have default constructor.

You can find informations [here](http://cuda-programming.blogspot.fr/2013/01/what-is-constant-memory-in-cuda.html)

If your object is complex and hard to copy, maybe you can look for : [Unified memory](http://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/unified-memory-in-cuda-6/), then just pass your variable by value to your kernel.

Comment: You should remain that the constant memory is only of 64 KB and may not be enough for the class domain.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I'm trying to implement unified memory now, but I'm running into a snag with inherited classes.  I posted a new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31616355/unified-memory-and-abstract-base-classes-in-cuda) if you're interested.